How to parametrize a Vault Named Query .orderBy() function in Corda R3 v5.2?
I'm currently using Corda R3 5.2 and planning to switch to Corda R3 5.3 as soon as it is released.
I'm currently working with Corda and specifically utilizing Vault-Named Queries to perform custom queries on states in the Vault. I am using the VaultNamedQueryBuilderFactory and VaultNamedQueryFactory to create a named query. Below is an example:
    vaultNamedQueryBuilderFactory.create("MY_NAMED_QUERY")
        .whereJson(
            "WHERE (visible_states.custom_representation -> 'com.acme' ->> 'person' = :person OR :person = '')" +
            "AND (visible_states.custom_representation -> 'com.acme' -> 'attributes' ->> 'documentId' = :documentId OR :documentId = '')"
        )
        .orderBy(?sortingParameterOne?, ?sortingParameterOneDirection?)
        .orderBy(?sortingParameterTwo?, ?sortingParameterTwoDirection?)
        .register()

In the Flow that queries the Vault Named Query, I'm using the following:
val resultSet = ledgerService.query("MY_NAMED_QUERY", StateAndRef::class.java)
    .setParameter("person", flowParameters.person)
    .setParameter("documentId", flowParameters.documentId)
    .setParameter("sortingParameterOne", flowParameters.sortingParameterOne)
    .setParameter("sortingParameterOneDirection", flowParameters.sortingParameterOneDirection)
    .setCreatedTimestampLimit(Instant.now()).setLimit(1000)
    .execute()

    val resultState = resultSet.results.map { it.state.documentState as DocumentState }
    results = resultState.map { it.documentAttributes.withoutNullFields() }

    return jsonMarshallingService.format(results) // End of the flow

I'm trying to parameterize sorting options such as sortingParameterOne, sortingParameterOneDirection to make the named query flexible for different use cases.
How can I achieve parameterized sorting and pagination with Vault Named Queries in Corda 5.2? For instance, how can I pass the sorting parameter and its direction dynamically?

Additionally, I'm looking for clarification regarding parameterizing the VaultNamedQueryStateAndRefFilter.
In particular, I want to understand if it's possible to insert parameters in the following filter method:
fun filter(data: StateAndRef<PraticaState>, parameters: MutableMap<String, Any>)

If I want to pass parameters to this filter function, what would be the best approach to do so?
